# How to filter out rows in a DataFrame that differ by a sign?

Tags: python, pandas, filtering

I have a DataFrame whose rows are arrays of numbers of some given length. I want to effectively get rid of those rows that differ by the sign of -1 from other rows. For example, if I encounter

```
 1 -2  2  4 -4

-1  2 -2 -4  4
```

then I want to drop one of them. Is there a not overly expensive way of doing that in Python/Pandas?

An example of such a DataFrame to be found [here](http://users.math.cas.cz/~kania/example_csv.csv).

Comment: Can you provide an example database? See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples

Comment: @TomekKania could you provide few more rows?

Comment: @YOLO - More rows is in csv in link.

Comment: @TomekKania - Can you add expected output?

Answer (score 1):

So there's one trick you can do,

**Only if you have an odd number of columns**

This way, you can invert the sign of any entry that has more than `ceil(n_cols/2.0)` negative values and then perform `drop_duplicates`.

```
from math import ceil
df = pd.read_csv('example_csv.csv')
cols = df.columns
df['n_minus'] = (df<0).sum(axis=1)
df.loc[df['n_minus']>ceil(len(cols)/2.0),cols] = df.loc[df['n_minus']>ceil(len(cols)/2.0),cols]*-1.0
new_df = df[cols].drop_duplicates()
```